# Is there a way to alias `:w'` to `:w`, to avoid creating files named '?

Tags: command-line, save, key-bindings

Occasionally, my pinky will graze the `'` key while reaching for enter, resulting in `:w'<Enter>`.

I've tried:

```
cabbrev w' :w
cabbrev w\' :w
cabbrev "w'" :w
```

None of them work.  Is there a way to alias `:w'` to `:w`?

I also use cmdwin (`:help cmdwin` + `nnoremap : :<C-F>`) instead of the normal command-line, so bonus points if it works there too.

Comment: hah; I have the same problem with the \

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Peter Rincker points out, `cmap`s can expand in other places as well, so a [`cnoreabbrev` would be better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513380/vim-change-x-function-to-delete-buffer-instead-of-save-quit):

```
cnoreabbrev w' w
```

Or, the safest, again thanks to Peter:

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> w' getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == "w'" ? "w" : "w'"
```

By explicitly checking if the command line contains only `w'`, unwanted expansions in situations can be avoided.

You can use a [`cmap`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Acmap):

```
cmap w' w
```

You'd still have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but an accidental `'` should be ignored now.

If you're using `cmdwin`, a `inoremap` set by `autocmd` might be useful:

```
autocmd CmdwinEnter * inoremap w' w
autocmd CmdwinLeave * iunmap w'
```

Comment: I ran `:cmap w' w`, but there was no change in behavior.  `:w'` still results in writing to a file named `'`. `"'" [New] 0L, 0C written`.

Comment: @mwcz Does the `'` actually show up when you press it after `w`? It shouldn't if the `cmap` was successfully created - a cmap LHS is automatically filled in with the RHS, so if you press a `'`, it should still only show `w`.

Comment: Be careful with bare `cmap`'s and `cabbrev`'s. They will execute/expand in other modes and other places. e.g. `:s/'follow'/foo` and `/'follow'`. Please see the following [vim change :x function to delete buffer instead of save & quit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7513380/438329) or use [cmdalias.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746)

Comment: Better safe than sorry: `cnoreabbrev <expr> w' getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == "w'" ? "w" : "w'"`

Comment: Yes, the `'` still shows up, but I just figured out it's because I'm using cmdwin to enter commands, and cmdwin is just a regular buffer, so `cmap/cnoreabbrev` don't work there.  Updating the answer with `noreabbrev` option for cmdwin users. :)  Thanks!!!

Comment: @muru no problem.  It's not a plugin. `:help cmdwin`.  It lets you edit `:` commands in a regular buffer, so you can use vim to edit commands.  I jumped the gun though, `noreabbrev` doesn't actually work in cmdwin.

Comment: @mwcz Try an `inorebbrev` or `inoremap`. I updated with a couple of `autocmd`s that seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This method works for me:

```
:ca w' w
```

Alternatively you can set up your vim to save the current buffer when you hit Esc twice, e.g.

```
:map <Esc><Esc> :w<CR>
```

Or use the following mapping to save file either by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>:

```
nmap <c-s> :w<CR>
vmap <c-s> <Esc><c-s>gv
imap <c-s> <Esc><c-s>

nmap <F2> :update<CR>
vmap <F2> <Esc><F2>gv
imap <F2> <c-o><F2>
```

<sup>Note: F2 only saves if necessary, and returns the user to insert mode (or restores their visual selection), as needed.</sup>

Source: [Saving a file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Saving_a_file) at vim wikia

Or use the following alternatives:

- `:up` (`:update`) for `:w`
- <kbd>ZQ</kbd> for `:q`
- <kbd>ZZ</kbd> for `:wq` or `:x`

Comment: Notice the quotation mark in the question.  `:w'`, not `:w`.  I want to use `:w` without accidentally hitting `'`, which writes a file I must then `rm \'`.  Good tips, though.

Comment: Ctrl-S doesn't send a sigstop - if the program stops, it's probably because a buffer was full. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13629/whats-the-difference-between-the-s-and-z-control-characters-inside-a-terminal'