# What are the differences between the map, noremap, abbrev and noreabbrev commands?

Tags: key-bindings, abbreviations

These commands transform one set of keystrokes to another in some way, but I am somewhat fuzzy on which one is most appropriate for some situation. In addition, there are the `!` variants of them as well. At the moment, my usage of them is pretty haphazard, so could I know what are the pitfalls associated with each? In particular notes about the various mode versions could be useful, since I learnt from Peter Rincker [in a comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/is-there-a-way-to-alias-w-to-w-to-avoid-creating-files-named/2008#comment1345_2008) that `cmap` can expand pretty much anywhere in the line and not only when I'm using `:` commands. What precautions can I take against potential pitfalls?

Comment: The next part is a bit meta: Which form should we use while answering on this site? - should I ask this on Meta, or add it to the question?

Comment: I would say it depends. I would always use noremap version if demonstrating a mapping. This way, people get in the habit of using the non-recursive mappings over the recursive versions. Unless of course, there is a reason to use map specifically, for instance, in a <Plug> mapping.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First, `map` and `noremap` are similar in that that each create mappings for normal,  visual, select and operator pending modes *simultaneously*. Vim details this in `:help map-overview`:

```
Overview of which map command works in which mode.  More details below.
     COMMANDS                    MODES ~
:map   :noremap  :unmap     Normal, Visual, Select, Operator-pending
:nmap  :nnoremap :nunmap    Normal
:vmap  :vnoremap :vunmap    Visual and Select
:smap  :snoremap :sunmap    Select
:xmap  :xnoremap :xunmap    Visual
:omap  :onoremap :ounmap    Operator-pending
:map!  :noremap! :unmap!    Insert and Command-line
:imap  :inoremap :iunmap    Insert
:lmap  :lnoremap :lunmap    Insert, Command-line, Lang-Arg
:cmap  :cnoremap :cunmap    Command-line
```

As per the above help, if you wanted to restrict the mapping to a specific mode, you have to prepend:

'n' (for normal), 'v' (for visual and select), 'c' (for command), 'x' (for visual mode), 's' (for select), 'o' (for operator pending).

For instance,

`nmap n nzz`

will create a normal mode, recursive mapping of `n`.

Now, `noremap` is just a non-recursive version of `map`.

So what is non-recursive mapping? Vim has the answer to that too, with `:help map-recursive`:

```
If you include the {lhs} in the {rhs} you have a recursive mapping.  When
{lhs} is typed, it will be replaced with {rhs}.  When the {lhs} which is
included in {rhs} is encountered it will be replaced with {rhs}, and so on.
This makes it possible to repeat a command an infinite number of times.  The
only problem is that the only way to stop this is by causing an error.  The
macros to solve a maze uses this, look there for an example.  There is one
exception: If the {rhs} starts with {lhs}, the first character is not mapped
again (this is Vi compatible).
For example: >
   :map ab abcd
will execute the "a" command and insert "bcd" in the text.  The "ab" in the
{rhs} will not be mapped again.
```

An example of this is mapping the following:

`:imap j k`

`:imap k j`

Now, vim will replace j with k and k with j infinite number of times, and will therefore show you an error that you have created a recursive mapping.

This is why it is generally recommended that you *almost always* (except when you have `<Plug>` mappings or similar) use non-recursive mappings. This prevents Vim hanging when you inadvertently create recursive mappings. The non-recursive mapping is therefore a more safer way to map commands in Vim.

With the above information at hand, we can see that `:noreabbrev` is just a non-recursive version of `:abbrev` command.

You can use `:abbrev` only in insert, replace and command modes. `:abbrev` is used for creating abbreviations, (aka shortcuts that Vim can expand). The short expanation is to use `:map`/`:noremap` to create mappings, `:abbrev`/`:noreabbrev` to create abbreviations, or whenever you want Vim to expand out your typing.

Comment: Avoiding hangs isn't the only reason to use the `nore` forms of the map command. Another (and in my opinion, more important) reason to use them is that they make your mappings reliable/predictable. If you use the plain form and the `rhs` contains a key that happens to be mapped to something else, then your mapping could have entirely different behaviour than intended.

Comment: What's the difference between map and remap?

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation and illustration of the `map`/`noremap` distinction.  (Merely saying that the `noremap`s don't expand recursively, etc., as in some of the answers to [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776117/what-is-the-difference-between-the-remap-noremap-nnoremap-and-vnoremap-mapping) on Stackoverflow, is intelligible to anyone who knows what "recursive" means, but doesn't convey why one should care.)

Comment: @Magnus, there is no `remap` afaik.