# Toggling comments on and off

Tags: comments

I have the following within my .vimrc:

```
" toggle comments
noremap <C-m> :<Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>exe "<Right><Right><Right><C-Right><Right>normal! I".g:commentType<CR>
autocmd BufReadPost *.php let g:commentType='//'      "Perl files
autocmd BufReadPost *.styl let g:commentType='//' "C files
autocmd BufReadPost *.js let g:commentType='//' "C files
```

I want it so if I do 'ctrl+m' on a line that is already commented, it'll uncomment it, and if the line doesn't have comments, it'll add it

So

```
blah blah text
```

becomes

```
// blah blah text
```

and if I do it again

```
// blah blah text
```

becomes

```
blah blah text
```

How may i do this?

Comment: Why do you have so many `<left>` and `<right>`? This works just fine for me: `noremap <C-m> :exe "normal! I".g:commentType<CR>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you're willing to use a plugin, there are many commenting plugins out there. Some of the most popular examples are:

- [tpope/vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary)
- [tomtom/tcomment_vim](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim)
- [scrooloose/nerdcommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter)

All of these have mappings for toggling comments. You can remap `<C-m>` to this command. For example, if you go with tpope/commentary, you could do:

```
nmap <C-m> gcc
```

which toggles a line.

If you don't want to install a plugin, you'll need to write a vimscript that detects if a line starts with a comment, and then adds or removes it accordingly. This is definitely possible, but I don't know how to do it myself, so I'll let someone else answer that if they want to.

Comment: I've tried  nnoremap <C-m> gcc with tpop vim commentary, but it doesn't work. Any idea why? gcc works tho.

Comment: @ditto Whoops, my bad. I say `nnoremap` by default. In this case you want `nmap` since `gcc` itself is a mapping. (see [here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2089/what-are-the-differences-between-the-map-noremap-abbrev-and-noreabbrev-command))

Comment: Awesome, have it working now. Tar. Am I able to highlight several rows and toggle them in 1 go? I've tried a few times and can't seem to get it working.

Comment: @ditto With `<C-m>`? Surround vim's mapping for visual mode is `gc` so if you want that to work you'll have to do `xmap <C-m> gc`.