# How to match pattern with buffer-scoped variable

Tags: substitute, variables

Goal: write code to do block commenting/uncommenting while keeping the current indentation level. [This has been solved, see here for my code](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/16122/17205)

Current problem: use s/// to match a line that begins with spaces/tabs and then a comment character, which will depend on the file being modified. In this case, I want to move from

```
    // this is a comment that can be toggled on/off
```

to

```
    this is a comment that can be toggled on/off
```

With my cursor on the commented line above:

```
:let b:commentChar='//'
:s@(^\s*)\=b:commentChar\s*@\1@
```

I have tried escaping the parentheses, escaping or unescaping the `=`, and using `\v` which someone told me would be "magic".

This does not work. (I didn't want to use `/` or `#` as the delimiter because my variable can be `//` or `#` and didn't want to use `:` as I need that for scoping with `b:commentChar`).

Comment: Related post: [Toggling comments on and off](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8160/778). Personally, I would stand on the shoulder's of giants and use a [plugin](https://vimawesome.com/?q=comment). I use [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary). That being said you may want to look into `:h :execute`, `:h escape()`, & `:h 'commentstring'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `\=` in the "search" portion of a `:substitute` command to introduce an expression. Actually, `\=` does have meaning in this context but it "matches 0 or 1 of the preceding atom, as many as possible," which is not what you want.

Instead, you should use `<c-r>=b:commentChar<cr>`.  This means literal `CTRL-R=` to introduce an expression and then `<cr>` to end the expression (copy and pasting this won't work).  Your substitute also uses `()` which means literal parentheses, not a group.  Here is a working command:

```
:s/\v(^\s*)\V<c-r>=escape(b:commentChar, '\/')<cr>\v\s*/\1/
```

This command:

- uses `\v` to make parentheses act as a group- not strictly necessary but it prevents the user's `magic` setting from interfering.
- `\V` before the expression to allow literal text and `\v` afterwards.
- `escape()` so we don't have to worry about any slashes in the expression so we can safely use `s//`.  Using `s@@` works too, but there is the (maybe remote) possibility that `b:commentChar` contains `@`.  `escape` handles all cases.

Again `<c-r>` and `<cr>` are literal characters you must type.  This is handled transparently in mappings, e.g., copy and pasting the following would work

```
nnoremap <leader>c :s/\v(^\s*)\V<c-r>=escape(b:commentChar, '\/')<cr>\v\s*/\1/<cr>
```

Alternatively, you could use `execute`:

```
execute 's/\v(^\s*)\V'.escape(b:commentChar, '\/').'\v\s*/\1/'
```

Comment: Will this command work in a function? I had `<cr>` in a function before and it nagged at me for trailing characters. Is there a command that will work in a function for this?

Comment: the last execute version will work in a function

Comment: Can you explain what the period does in the `execute` line? I'm trying to get an if statement to know if the line is commented.
I currently have `if match(getline(l:line), "^\s*".b:commentChar)>-1` but it doesn't work.

Comment: The periods mean string concatenation.  It doesn't work because you are using double quotes which requires backslashes to be escaped.  This works: `match(getline(l:line), '^\s*'.b:commentChar)>-1`.  Note the single quotes.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. I asked another question here https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15971/invalid-match-arguments . If you happen to have the time, any help you could provide would be awesome, but no worries if you're busy. Thanks again!