# Vim disables syntax highlighting after execution `autocmd BufAdd * exe 'buffer ' . expand('<abuf>')`

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

Following code switches off Vim syntax highlighting for buffers opened after its execution.

```
autocmd BufAdd * exe 'buffer ' . expand('<abuf>')
```

Why? Is it bug?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you add a new buffer to the buffer list, Vim will switch to it anyway (except `:badd` etc).

Comment: I try to map added buffer with `nmap <buffer>` on autocmd BufAdd event. For this I need to switch to added buffer with `exe 'buffer' . expand('<abuf>')` because as said in vim help: "When this autocommand is executed, the current buffer "%" may be different from the buffer being created "<afile>""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comment you describe, that you want to do `nmap <buffer>` on `BufAdd`
event.

The event `BufAdd` is very early in the processing, the use-cases for this
event are limited.
If you want to do buffer local mappings, you should do that with `autocmd BufEnter` or with `autocmd FileType`.

```
autocmd BufEnter *.c   nnoremap <buffer> ...
autocmd FileType c     nnoremap <buffer> ...
```

BTW: You should prefer `noremap` to `map`. See the answer to [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2089/what-are-the-differences-between-the-map-noremap-abbrev-and-noreabbrev-command).

---

Back to your initial question:

Autocmds are blocked while another autocmd is running. In your case, you use an
autocmd on `BufAdd` to immediately switch to the new buffer. Switching to a new
buffer needs to read the file and would normally trigger the `BufRead` and
`BufEnter` autocmds, that are used to determine the file type and hence the
syntax highlighting.

As this switch to the buffer is done in the context of an autocmd, the
`BufRead` and `BufRead` events are not triggered. So no file type detection and hence
no syntax highlighting.

**Don't use the following in your case, use another autocmd event  as described above.**

It is possible, to allow nested autocmds by adding the keyword `nested`, like:

```
autocmd BufAdd * nested ....
```

Then autocmds are triggered while the this autocmd is running.

You might want to read `:help autocmd-nested` for the details.