# Is there a way to bind `:qw` to `:wq`?

Tags: command

I often mistype `:wq` as `:qw`. I can't create a command for `qw` though since it doesn't start with an uppercase character. Is there a way I can bind `qw` to `wq`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enter the command `:cmap qw wq`. Entering it in as a command will set it for you current session. Put it as a line in your `.vimrc`
if you want it to be permanent.
A bit of explanation: `cmap` means create a mapping for command-line mode, which will transform the left expression into the right one after you press enter `<CR>` in the vim command-line (things you type after the colon `:`)

See `:help map` and section 40 of the user manual. http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_40.html

Comment: Yes, I thought of `x` after I wrote the answer. I'm still training myself to use it... It is the best solution. Is there, however, a way to remap `qw` to `wq` in command-line mode without knock-on effects?

Comment: How about the [classic](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2008/10604) `:cnoreabrrev <expr> qw getcmdtype() is# ':' && getcmdline() =~# '^\s*qw' ? 'wq' : 'qw'`